# iPhone dev - I want a custom UIView that is made up of many subviews. In what method should I add the subviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, initialization

Basically I want to have a custom UIView that has a bunch of buttons in it. Should I just add the buttons to the view inside initWithFrame? I also would like to set up all their locations in the view at the same time. Is there a customary place where all this would be done? I'm guessing I shouldn't do anything in drawRect since I'm not making any custom drawings, just adding buttons as subviews. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`initWithFrame:` is a good place to add the buttons.

If the buttons' frame depends on the parent view's size, you should set the `frame` of the buttons in the parent view's `layoutSubviews` method. Otherwise you can just specify the buttons' `autoresizingMask` when you add the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set up all their locations "at the same time", but if you call many `addSubview:` sequentially you don't see even that were added one at a time.
You do not always need to subclass `UIView`(if it is not particularly complex), you can create it at run time, add the components that you want with `initWithFrame:` and show it; otherwise you can subclass `UIView` just to create the layout (rounded border, gradient color, etc), initialize it from your class and add the components. If you have some problem, show us more details about your problem.